# Qual é o monitor de um método com modificadores static synchronized?

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Estou no aprendizado de Java pelo livro Java Para Iniciantes de Herbert Schildt. Estou aprendendo sobre threads, e, agora, sobre sincronização de threads. A minha dúvida é referente a um conceito chamado de "monitor".

Eu entendi que ele controla o acesso das threads de modo que pode bloquear outras threads de acessarem um mesmo recurso ao mesmo tempo e depois desbloquear para que outras threads tenham acesso ao recurso. Contudo, a minha dúvida se dá no seguinte: pelo que que eu li, todos os objetos tem um monitor, e é aí que a sincronização trabalha, correto? E a sincronização em Java ocorre principalmente com a palavra-chave `synchronized`, isso? Mas, pensando no `synchronized`, conseguimos usar ele em métodos `static`, algo assim:

```
public synchronized static void Método(){}
```

E no livro diz

> "quando esse método for chamado, a *thread* chamadora entrará no
> monitor do objeto, que então será bloqueado".

A minha dúvida é: qual objeto? Aqui não temos nenhum objeto, e inclusive o próprio método é estático.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É meio confuso, mas classes em Java também se refletem em (isto é, correspondem a) objetos da classe [java.lang.Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Esses objetos são instanciados [conforme](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) o *runtime* do Java necessita. Eles são acessados através da sintaxe `NomeDaClasse.class`.

É a esses objetos que pertencem os monitores referenciados por métodos `static synchronized`.

Note que esses monitores são diferentes dos monitores das instâncias normais de cada classe (isto é, dos objetos normais, que você cria com `new`).

Assim, podemos dizer que, da mesma forma que um método...

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    public synchronized void fazAlgo() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

é basicamente equivalente a...

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    public void fazAlgo() {
        synchronized(MinhaClasse.this) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

então também um método estático...

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    public static synchronized void fazAlgo() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

é basicamente equivalente a...

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    public static void fazAlgo() {
        synchronized(MinhaClasse.class) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

O objeto monitor pode ser verificado com o seguinte código:

```
public class TesteStaticSynchronized {
    public static synchronized void teste() {
        System.out.println(Thread.holdsLock(TesteStaticSynchronized.class));
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        teste();
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
true
```

Comment: Beleza cara, valeuuuuu me ajudou dms

Comment: Se puder rever a resposta, eu falei umas besteiras mas já corrigi.